# Find the value of k.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have trouble understanding how to solve this question. I understand how when $n$ is $0$, the value is $0$, but do not understand how to calculate the value of $k$ based on this.

> The first element of the sequence $a_1=0$, and if $n\geq 1$ then $a_{n+1} = a_n + (-1)^n\cdot n$. Find the value of $k$ if $a_k = 2013$.

Comment: What is $a_2$?  $a_3$?  $a_4$?  Can you find a pattern?

Comment: "I understand how when $n$ is $0$, the value is $0$": no, $a_0$ is not defined.

Comment: I meant when n is 0, it becomes a(0+1) = 0 ((0+1) as the subscript)

Comment: I think Yves is saying that there isn’t an $a_0$. The sequence starts with $a_1$. Note that the recursion defines $a_2$, $a_3$, etc when $n$ is 1, 2, etc because the recursion defines $a_{n*1}$, not $a_n$. It’s just a technical quibble, but important to notice. Moral: be precise!

Comment: Sure, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @V11: once again, no. You are not allowed to write $a_{0+1}=a_0+(-1)^0$ because this recurrence is said to hold for $n\ge1$. The value of $a_0$ cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have for any $n\geq 1$ that $$a_n=\begin{cases}(n-1)/2&n\text{ odd}\\-n/2&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$.

You can prove this by induction on $n$.

> Thus for $a_k=2013$, $k$ is odd as $2013>0$ and thus $2013=(k-1)/2$.

---

**Edit:** See below for a sketch of the proof:

As an induction base, let $n=1$, then $a_1=0$ and $(n-1)/2=0$.

For the induction step, let $a_n$ satisfy the formula for some $n$. we divide between the cases if $n$ is even or odd:

If $n$ is odd, then $a_n=(n-1)/2$ and $n+1$ is even. Now, $a_{n+1}=a_n+(-1)^n\cdot n$. By the induction hypothesis and as $n$ is odd, you have $a_{n+1}=(n-1)/2-n$, i.e. $a_{n+1}=n/2-1/2-n=-n/2-1/2=-(n+1)/2$.

If $n$ is even, you have $a_n=-n/2$ and $n+1$ is odd. Now, again $a_{n+1}=-n/2+n=n/2$ by the induction hypothesis and as $n$ is even. Now, $a_{n+1}=n/2=((n+1)-1)/2$.

---

**Edit:** Based on the suggestion of OP: To calculate the first few terms, we start with the given $a_1=0$. Then

- $a_2=a_{1+1}=a_1+(-1)^1\cdot 1=-1$
- $a_3=a_{2+1}=a_2+(-1)^2\cdot 2=-1+2=1$
- $a_4=a_{3+1}=a_3+(-1)^3\cdot 3=1-3=-2$
- ...

Comment: How did you get (n-1)/2 and -n/2?

Comment: @V11 I calculated the first eight terms by hand and then made this guess. After that, I proved this formula using induction on $n$. I've edited my question and added the induction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do you calculate the first eight terms? If n is 1, wouldn't it be a2 = a1 + (-1)^1 * 1 equal to a2 = a1 - 1 [All the numbers just beside a are in subscript form] (I know this is incorrect but I want know where I may be doing something wrong)

Comment: @V11 I've edited my answer to include some examples.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now till there now. How do you find out whether k is odd or even?

Comment: @V11 $a_k$ is negative if and only if $k$ is even.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take long to realize that the even $n$ correspond to a decreasing, negative sequence, and the odd $n$ to an increasing, non-negative one. So $k$ must be odd.

Then

$$a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}+(-1)^{2n}2n=a_{2n-1}+(-1)^{2n}2n+(-1)^{2n-1}(2n-1)=a_{2n-1}+1$$

and by induction

$$\color{green}{a_{2n+1}=n}.$$

Hence

$$k=2\cdot2013+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work (telescoping sum):

$2013-a_{k-1}=(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)$

$a_{k-1}-a_{k-2} =(-1)^{k-2}(k-2)$

........

$a_{2}-a_{1} = (-1)^1(1)$

So summing both sides we get $2013-a_{1}= \sum_{n=1}^{k}(-1)^n(n-1) $

Then you could split that sum into odd and even terms and use sum of first k terms formula to get a quadratic in $k$ - then solve for k.